# PySide: Returning a value from a slot

Tags: python, pyside, signals-slots

The Pyside [documentation](https://deptinfo-ensip.univ-poitiers.fr/ENS/pyside-docs/PySide/QtCore/Slot.html) states that slots can have return values, but I have yet to figure out how make it do so.

I couldn't find any usable code samples on this, so I've added a decorator as the docs suggest:

```
def testSlot(self):
    print('testSlot called')
    return 'RETURN VALUE RETURN VALUE RETURN VALUE'
```

And I'm trying to capture the return value like this:

```
ret = foo.testSignal.emit()
```

But it's not working. My test code, which you can find [here](http://pastie.org/private/o6oobwzkn0985xuazqlcag), also [crashes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXWr8.png) with [this](http://pastie.org/private/7vflfvqcsweeu6su8v6hda) error output. Help is appreciated!

**Edit:** I've removed the decorator, which solves the crashing issue, but it still doesn't return the value I want it to return.

Running the script as is give me this:

> foo.testSignal.emit()
>   testSlot called
>   True

Comment: You have two `@`s in the decorator

Comment: Whoops, don't know how that got in there. I fixed it, but it still crashes.

Comment: How does it crash? What is the full traceback?

Comment: It's giving me a ["python.exe has stopped working" message box](http://i.imgur.com/kQgS2uS.png?1). The full text from the problem details is [here](http://pastie.org/private/7vflfvqcsweeu6su8v6hda#6). Theres no output on the console. Also, it seemed that pastie was the one adding the extra `@`, it keeps adding it again after each repaste for some reason.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. A few things to try that have sometimes worked for me: `@Slot()` with no arguments. If that fails, remove the decorator entirely.

Comment: I've read that a lot of PySide methods crash if you call them before a QApplication has started. I don't know if that's still true in the newer versions, but that could be your problem.

Comment: Ok, removing the decorator stops the crashing, but it still doesn't give me the return value I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid what you think is not possible.
Signals and slots are loosely coupled together, so emitting a signal does not directly call a slot, and therefore **cannot retrieve "its" return value**.

This might be clearer if you think about this:

You can **connect 2 different slots** (of e.g. 2 different classes), which return different values, **to one signal**. Which of the two return values are supposed to reach the variable you try to assign?

What you probably mean is [this](https://deptinfo-ensip.univ-poitiers.fr/ENS/pyside-docs/PySide/QtCore/Slot.html): This is something completely different, and allows return values via "invoking" the method over the MetaObject system by "name".

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply, I'm out of the country and internet access has been limited. Can you elaborate on '"invoking" the method over the MetaObject system by "name"'? How would I go about capturing a return value with it?

Comment: You can "call" or "invoke" a method in Qt via the MetaObject system by its name (as QString) in C++, using [QMetaObject::invokeMethod](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod) - so this is dynamic, and not precompiled. It is needed for calling a C++ method from e.g. QML - QML can only call methods that are known by the MetaObject system. So Q_INVOCABLE is needed for making the function known - and if you want a return value from e.g. PySide into QML, you have no Q_INVOCABLE - you just have to declare a Slot, which then is automagically known to the MetaObject system.

Comment: This is the right answer.  A slight quibble is that by default, emitting a signal is direct (synchronous) not queued (asynchronous) so you might think of it as a 'direct call' in the sense that execution continues in the signal handler, but as described, possibly in several signal handlers, in the order in which they were connected.  Also, why does such erroneous code crash and what tools exist to warn that you are connecting to a handler that erroneously returns a value?

Comment: Hm. Not really true. Per default signal-slot-connections are `ÀutonConnection`s: within the same thread, they are direct calls (faster), but within different threads, they are `QueuedConnection`s - called async. So unless you pass DirectConnection to a different-threaded signal-slot-pair, you are safe. See http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtCore/Qt.html and http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/threads-qobject.html#signals-and-slots-across-threads.

Answer (score 1):

This question is old but it seems now there is a way to do return a value from a slot call (call **python/PySide2** slot from **QML**):

**Python Side (Slot)**:

```py
# Main.py
# add imports ... 

# Class to set the context on QML frontend
class PythonQObject(QObject):

  @Slot(result=int)
  def returnSomeInt(self):
    return 456


# Set the context etc, on main
if __name__ == "__main__":
  pyQObject = PythonQObject()
  app = QApplication(sys.argv)
  engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
  engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("backend", pyQObject )
  engine.load(os.path.join(basedir, 'main.qml'))
  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**QML Side:**

```
/* main.qml */
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Window {
    id: mainWindow

    Component.onCompleted: {
        /* Get the return value from slot here */
        let value = backend.returnSomeInt()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you may "inject" whatever you want to return from testSlot function into a property of the class where the signal is emmited